# Javascript - HTML / Is this possible?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use 'this' in this scenario?

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

 for (var i = 0; i<td.length; i++){
    td[i].id = 'abc' + i;
};
 
for (var i = 0; i<td.length; i++){
    td[i].onclick = changeColor(this.id) **<--- I need this to send the 
                                                          element's ID**
};
```

What Im trying to do here is assign the same 'onclick' function to all my  elements.
And making the elements send their id when clicking on them.

Comment: which `this` of what ?

Comment: what is td? what is cambiarColor ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: do `td[i].onclick = cambiarColor`, then inside the cambiarColor function get it (this) from the event

Comment: Do both in a single ‘for’ loop, no need for two of them. Then you’ll have access to the ID easily.

Comment: Please don't add answers to your questions. I have rolled back/edited your question. Please write a new answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to use `this` in an event handler to refer to the element on which an event handler is listening, but the post does need some correction.

```
for (var i = 0; i<td.length; i++){
   td[i].onclick = cambiarColor(this.id);
};
```

calls `cambiarColor` within the loop, using the `this` value current when the loop executes. Most likely the intention was to call `cambiarColor` when the click event occurs, as in

```
  td[i].onclick = function(event) {cambiarColor(this.id)}
```

Notice the use of a `function` declaration to defer calculation of the `this` value until after the function is called. An arrow function would not work here.

**Alternatives**

```
 td[i].onclick = cambiarColor;
```

would assign `cambiarColor` as the event handler directly so that when called it would see the `td` item element as its `this` value. The handler would need to be coded to use the `this` keyword, as for example

```
function cambiarColor( event) {
    this.style.color = "red"; // change text color to red
}
```

but `this` will again have the wrong value if `cambiarColor` is an arrow function.

Another alternative is to use either `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` properties to determine the element on which an event was fired or is being handled respectively. For example:

```
 function cambiarColor(event) {
     event.target.style.color = "red"; // change text color to red
     const id = event.target.id;  // the id of the element if still needed
     ...
 }
```

This alternative does not require the use of `this`. Note `event.target` only differs from `event.currentTarget` when set to  a child or descendant element of `currentTarget` that generated the event.

---

For completeness, assigning a function to an element's `onclick` property internally calls `addEventListener` to attach the listener to the element. For more generalised code you could call it explicitly, like

```
  td[i].addeventListener( "click", function(event) {cambiarColor(this.id)}
```

although this way of adding the click handler won't update the element's `onclick` property.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but it might not do what you expect. `this` refers to the context: the function you're using `this` in (or the context the function was bound to with `.bind()`, the object it's in, the class its in, etc. With arrow functions, the context (what `this` refers to) is carried over from the parent context rather than referring to that function.

If you use `this` outside of a function, object, class, etc., you're referring to the global context. In the browser, that means the window (`console.log(window === this)` to test). In Node, instead of window, you have `global` (the same test in a Node repl would show that).

So yes, you can use `this`, but it's not going to be the `this` you want unless you have that loop in an object/class/function that has an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it by

document.getElementByClassName('')

you just have to give same class too every element